userbot pyrogram Does it affect the account?
A question that confuses me: Does Pyrogram Userbot affect my account (prevent, remove account, etc.) or no
All codes are very normal, for example (letter decoration, weather, group control commands)
But one code I fear is that it may affect the account (the order to save restricted content (text, image, video, file........))
@app.on_message(filters.regex(r"^(طقس)"))
I think that it affects conditions, for example (installation on a specific user so that you can take it if it becomes available, or processes that affect or load heavily on servers below
```
